# Select between a range of number insert if doesn't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Can i select between 1 - 20  which number doesnt exist from this table and then insert one of my numbers  into an sql column?

```
example i have in my table   1
                             2 
                             9
                             13

if not exists select ('%[1-20]%',column from table); insert into table select....?
```

- I dont want insert all numbers which not exist i want one of them

Answer (score 0):

Use numbers [table](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/)..

```
;With cte
as
(
select top 20 number
from numbers
order by number
)
Insert into yourtable
select top 1* from cte c1 where not exists(select 1 from yourtable t2 where t1.number=t2.id)
```

You also can use join..

```
Insert into yourtable
select top 1 number 
from
numbers n
join
yourtable t
on t.id<>n.number
and n<=20
```

Comment: Thnak you for answer,i will check it and i'll return